# Pandas - Computing the mean vector of a window when the start is column specific

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data:

```
In [79]:

df = pd.DataFrame( data=nr.randn(8,4), index=pd.date_range( '2014-01-01', periods=8 ), columns=string.split( 'z a o p' ) )
df
Out[79]:
z   a   o   p
2014-01-01   0.737081    0.409902    0.077970    1.710260
2014-01-02  -0.686835   -1.588592    0.652161   -1.196529
2014-01-03  -1.217688   -1.156016    1.448976    0.415068
2014-01-04   0.336256   -0.559507    0.917721    0.106411
2014-01-05   0.043473   -1.221673   -0.598708    1.489676
2014-01-06  -0.858759    0.508017   -1.611998    0.581115
2014-01-07  -0.672269   -0.247206   -0.312354    0.493086
2014-01-08   1.346462   -1.805292    2.807642    0.365685
8 rows × 4 columns
```

And for each column, I have a start date:

```
In [83]:
start = pd.Series( data=pd.to_datetime( [ '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06', '2014-01-06', '2014-01-03' ] ), index=string.split( 'z a o p' ) )
start
Out[83]:
z   2014-01-05
a   2014-01-06
o   2014-01-06
p   2014-01-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]
In [94]:
```

The desired output is the mean vector of the 4 red vectors, where each red vector is centered around the corresponding start date:

[image: Desired output]

My current solution is very straightforward. I just loop, add and divide:

```
res = pd.Series( data=[0.] * 3 )
for name, dt in start.iteritems() :
    res += df.loc[ dt - datetime.timedelta( days=1 ): dt + datetime.timedelta( days=1 ), name ].values
res /= 4
res
Out[94]:
0   -0.670163
1   -0.161360
2   -0.327977
dtype: float64
```

I am wondering if there is a slicker solution using pandas built-in functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be done with the following:

```
np.array([np.diagonal(df.shift(i).loc[start]) for i in [-1, 0, 1]]).mean(1)
```

Basically, `df.shift(0).loc[start]` gives a 4x4, and we only want the the diagonal elements. Then we shift the 4x4 up and down to get the other two values we want for each column. Put all into an `array` and get the `.mean()`.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the rolling mean column-wise for a window of 3

```
In [42]: x = pd.rolling_mean(df,window=3)

In [43]: x
Out[43]: 
                   z         a         o         p
2014-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-01-02       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2014-01-03 -0.052058  0.236828  0.458659 -0.945181
2014-01-04 -0.171851  0.522897  0.677144  0.136008
2014-01-05 -0.538397  0.737885  0.257929  0.765763
2014-01-06 -0.809379 -0.117525  0.605199  0.422414
2014-01-07 -0.931384  0.346631  1.000791  0.428991
2014-01-08 -0.484385  0.034858  1.042445  0.362800
```

Select out the pairs of column/index that we want (the unstack creates a multi-index with these pairs)

```
In [44]: x.unstack().loc[list(start.iteritems())]
Out[44]: 
z  2014-01-05   -0.538397
a  2014-01-06   -0.117525
o  2014-01-06    0.605199
p  2014-01-03   -0.945181
dtype: float64
```

Final mean if you need it is a simple mean of the Series from 44

```
In [45]: x.unstack().loc[list(start.iteritems())].mean()
Out[45]: -0.24897596517522122
```

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding. In my example, the output is `m.mean(axis=1)`, where `m` is the `(4x3)` matrix with red vectors as columns. Your solution seems to output `m.mean(axis=0)`

Comment: you can easily do that..typing was quick